# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges on insert

Tags: c, oracle

There is a change in data type of e one column from NUMBER(4) to VARCHAR2(4).
DBA did the conversion of exiting values.

Now When we are trying insert the record into table using proc * c code it is giving error "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges".

From SQLPLUS we are able to insert the records. After sometime problem gets disappeared. Once DBA rebuild the table and problem disappeared.

This problem occurs after every time we refresh the testing environment with new changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "rebuild the table" and "refresh" the test environment? What is being performed? If you drop and recreate the table (or your user or roles), you need to grant the insert privileges again, or you will definitely get the ORA-01031 error message.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, don't forget your semicolons, and remember arrays start at index `0`.

Answer (score 6):

Run this line:

```
grant insert on [table] to [user]
```

change `[table]` to your table name and change `[user]` to your user.

Answer (score 3):

There are some possibilities.

Double check your table privileges by running the following SQL command:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_tab_privs tp
 WHERE tp.owner = '<YOUR_OWNER>'
       AND tp.table_name = '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>';
```

In the case your privilege is granted through a role make sure the role is enabled by checking that the GRANTEE above, in this query below, is shown with the attribute "DEFAULT_ROLE" = YES.

```
SELECT * FROM dba_role_privs rp WHERE rp.grantee = '<USER_RUNNING_THE_INSERT>';
```

If it's not, and assuming there is no security issues with your DBA and application design, you can enable it by running this:

```
alter user <YOUR_USER_RUNNING_THE_INSERT> default role all;
```

Then again, make sure if you're recreating the table, that every time you drop it and create again, you run your grants accordingly.