# while inserting data to oracle from csv file using python getting error ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: python, oracle, csv, oracle11g

I am trying to load data to oracle table. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447835/loading-csv-file-contents-to-oracle-using-cx-oracle-and-getting-select-keyword-e) is my previous question where i have posted whole code how I am doing that .

this is the code:

```
def Create_list():
reader = csv.reader(open("Query_result_combined.csv","r"))
lines=[]
print("Creating a list")
for line in reader:
    lines.append(line)
return lines


def Insert_data():
#connection logic goes here 
print("Connecting Now!!")
#conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
con = cx_Oracle.connect(db_user,db_password,db_connection_name)
print("Connected to Oracle!!")
lines=Create_list()
cur=con.cursor()
print("Inserting data")
for line in lines:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO A608232_QUERY_RESULT (InteractionId,QueryId,Score,StartOffsetInMs,EndOffsetInMs,SpeakerRole,QueryIdentity,SpeakerId) VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8)",line)
con.commit ()
cur.close()
print("completed")
```

So i rectified all aproches suggested in answer to my question so that error has been solved now i am getting this new error `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

when i loaded the data directly in to oracle using import option that data is getting loaded. When i am trying to read the same file in this code and trying to push the data i am getting this error.

I print lines[:1] and lines[:2] this is the output I get:

```
[['InteractionId', 'QueryId', 'Score', 'StartOffsetInMs', 'EndOffsetInMs', 
'SpeakerRole', 'QueryIdentity', 'SpeakerId']]
[['InteractionId', 'QueryId', 'Score', 'StartOffsetInMs', 'EndOffsetInMs', 
'SpeakerRole', 'QueryIdentity', 'SpeakerId'], ['34118470', '27', '45.63345', 
'89900', '90980', 'U', 'e54fd492-8877-4534-997b-9dbe9a8fbd74', '']]
 Inserting data
```

can someone please point out the mistake that i am doing in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a title line in your csv file, which is not part of the numerical data. You have to skip it using `next(reader)` just after mapping the `csv.reader` on the file handle.

Aside: use a context manager to ensure the file will be closed, and, no need for a loop, just convert the row iterator to a list (when the first line has been skipped) to read all the lines (will be faster)

```
def Create_list():
    with open("Query_result_combined.csv","r") as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       next(reader)  # skips title line
       return list(lines)  # directly iterate on the rest of the lines
```

Comment: I didnt the part where you said for loop is not needed. ? How to do that exactly

Comment: `list(lines)` just creates the list of lines, like if you did a loop + append. But faster and shorter. I rewrote my version of your `Create_list`

Comment: Thanks the problem solved. I was reading my headers as well hence data was not inserted in to csv